# WCF Timeout with no trace

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a wcf windows service using ipc binding, and the client is an IIS webservice.  During debugging, I keep getting the error below:

> System.TimeoutException occurred
>   Message: Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
>   Additional information: The pipe connection was aborted because an asynchronous read from the pipe did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:02:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

The weird thing is that it does not cause any errors on the client.  And putting break points along the calls does not help, or get triggered.

I tried editing the Exception Settings of Visual Studio 2015 to break on this exception.  It does, but "no source code available" is displayed.

Last weird thing, I have edited all the timeouts of both the server and client to be 30 seconds, and it still fails at 2 minutes.

Server config:

```
 <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="ipcBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:30" openTimeout="00:00:30"
      receiveTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:30" maxConnections="10000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="0" maxStringContentLength="0" maxArrayLength="52428800"
        maxBytesPerRead="0" maxNameTableCharCount="0" />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

...

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyService">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="5242880" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10000" maxConcurrentSessions="5000"
        maxConcurrentInstances="5000" />
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:00:30" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Client config:

```
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="ipcBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:30" openTimeout="00:00:30"
      receiveTimeout="00:00:30" sendTimeout="00:00:30" maxConnections="5000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="52428800" />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

**edit:**  I created a brand new client using .NET 4.6 (Console app), and it works fine, the errors never appear.  But I have narrowed it down to only happening when my WinForms client makes the remoting calls.  Both use the exact same ClientBase implementation and are enclosed in a `using` statement.

Comment: Use WCF tracing, You will get more information about the error

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately the error is the same and gives no details to the offending call.

Comment: @Mike_G I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: @BlueStrat Yes, I found the answer to a lot of issues I had with WCF.  It comes down to the way I was disposing of the WCF clients when an exception occurs.  http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/

Comment: @Mike_G, thanks for the feedback. In my case it seems that duplex channels don't like being closed from the client after every operation, they seem to be designed to be kept perpetually open. I use a similar approach to your blog solution in order to safely "use" the proxies, however yours is more elegant!  Extension methods (vs an auxiliary class as with my current approach) is the way to go.  Thank you!